# Is SecureRandom.nextBytes() the only way to set initial seed for an SecureRandom instance?

Tags: java, security, random, seed

I've seen many toturials for SecureRandom to give the following example:

```
SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
random.nextBytes(new byte[20]);
```

From the document, when an SecureRandom instance is created, it is not seeded yet. The nextBytes() method will invoke the default seeding for it. Therefore, I also see the following suggestion:

> If using SHA1PRNG, always call java.security.SecureRandom.nextBytes(byte[]) immediately after creating a new instance of the PRNG.

My first question is:
Is it a must? Can I also seed it with:

```
SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
sandom.setSeed(random.generateSeed(20));
```

Is it also an secure way to seed it?

My Second question is about reseeding.

> The setSeed(long seed) method of java.security.SecureRandom class is used to reseeds this random object, using the eight bytes contained in the given long seed. The given seed supplements, rather than replaces, the existing seed. Thus, repeated calls are guaranteed never to reduce randomness.

So, it means once I instantly call the nextBytes to invoke the default seeding. It will be always secure regardless of what the reseeding seed is, correct?
Does it mean the following code which gives a hardcoded seed is also secure:

```
SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
random.nextBytes(new byte[20]);
//reseed after usage
random.setSeed(new byte[]{0x(90),0x(15)});
```

I am also confused with the tutorial https://howtodoinjava.com/java8/secure-random-number-generation/
There is a subsection 2.3:

> 2.3. Provide more opportunities increase entropy
>
> > Create a new instance of SecureRandom periodically and reseed, like this:

```
SecureRandom sr = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG", "SUN");
sr.setSeed(SecureRandom.generateSeed(int))
```

> > Periodic reseeding defends against data disclosure if a seed is leaked. If using SHA1PRNG, always call java.security.SecureRandom.nextBytes(byte[]) immediately after creating a new instance of the PRNG.

This is confusing for me. Is it paradoxical? Why the code example it gives doesn't call nextBytes immediately but use setSeed? Is it reseeding? I suppose reseeding is repeatedly seeding the same SecureRandom instance. But the SecureRandom sr = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG", "SUN")  generates a new secureRandom instance, right? Can we just use one secureRandom instance but periodically call setSeed() to reseed it?

Comment: A `SecureRandom` is always seeded. The call to `nextBytes(byte[])` is to prevent someone being able to establish what the initial state was; theoretically, if you can see the first **x** values, you can predict all subsequent values (made even easier if the PRNG uses a short set of initial values).

Comment: I don't think so. From the official document (https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/security/SecureRandom.html), it also points out that the created SecureRandom is not seeded. For the initial state, the secureRandom instance is always required to reseed when using again. So there are no worries about leakage for the subsequent values from the initial state.

Comment: Perhaps, it depends on what you mean by "seed"; for example *please note that reseed may not be supported by all SecureRandom implementations* and *depending on the implementation, the generateSeed, reseed and nextBytes methods may block as entropy is being gathered, for example, if the entropy source is /dev/random on various Unix-like operating systems.* - which basically means, if the `SecureRandom` is un-seeded it will still behave as if it were seeded.

Comment: It seems that the "reseed" API is not always supported. But reseeding by calling setSeed should always work. It points out  Unix-like set seed from /dev/random. But I don't think it means this default seeding is always done when creating an SecureRandom instance calling new SecureRandom().

Comment: If you were correct, calling `new SecurRandom();` and then generating an `int` should ***always*** return the same `int`. It does not. I **think** there is an android bug where it might, but unless you're on android it doesn't matter.

Comment: No, it definitely returns different int. Because the methods next(), and other inherited method like ints(), they will invoke nextBytes() internally. Therefore, you can create an SecureRandom instance and use these method immediately to generate next bytes/int securely. The seeding doesn't happen at the secureRandom instance creation. It happened when you calling this method. However if you use setSeed() before those next*** method, the default seeding will not happen.